# Bootstrap nav bar brand image vertically center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm playing around with a bootstrap theme. Here the problem was `navbar-brand` image is not vertically align center with the navbar.

[Live demo](https://agrowcell-48237.firebaseapp.com/)

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="nave_menu">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="./images/Agrocell.png" alt="" style="max-width:140px;">
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#features">FEATURES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#abouts">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#special">PRODUCTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#footer">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: `.navbar-brand { padding-top: 0;}`

Comment: `.navbar-brand>img { position: absolute;}`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.container-fluid { margin-top: 20px; }` from style.css and add `#bs-example-nav-collapse-1 { margin-top: 20px;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by new feature of CSS3 flexbox, for that you need to apply some CSS on your classes.

```
.container-fluid {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0 15px;  // for remove top padding
}

.collapse.navbar-collapse {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

from that your navbar is vertically center.